# Dois bancos de dados com PDO PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

Estou tentando fazer uma conexão com dois bancos de dados com `PDO` ta assim.

`Config.php`

```
<?php
  class config{
  var $host = 'meuhost';
  var $usuario = 'meuusuario';
  var $senha = 'minhasenha';
  var $db = 'banco1','banco2';

  }
?>
```

E onde estou fazendo a classe esta assim.

```
<?php

   include_once 'config.php';

    class conecta extends config
    {
        var $pdo;

        function __construct()
        {
             $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.
                $this->host.';dbname='.
                $this->db, $this->usuario, $this->senha); 
        }
     }
?>
```

so que não estou sabendo fazer a função `construct` conectar com os dois bancos so com o `banco1`.

Comment: Nao vai dar certo desta forma